# what is the role of categorization in database?

Tags: database, categorization

let me know what categorization is in database and what role of it is ...

i got it from a site, i do not understand...
Categorisation is a process of modelling of a single subtype (or subclass) with a relationship that involves more than one distinct supertype (or superclass). Till now all the relationships that have been discussed, are a single distinct supertype. However, there could be need for modelling a single supertype/subtype relationship with more than one supertype, where the supertypes represent different entity set.

thanks!

https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=9m382yDgxRsC&pg=PA287&lpg=PA287&dq=7.4.+Categorisation+Categorisation+is+a+process+of+modelling+of+a+single+subtype+(or+subclass)+with+a+relationship+that+involves+more+than+one+distinct+supertype+(or+superclass).&source=bl&ots=7JFawUEg3d&sig=peeXz5QajJFdkFHw0TzlvQFwix8&hl=ko&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi1u8iHwIHSAhWMVhQKHfr_AkkQ6AEIIDAA#v=onepage&q=7.4.%20Categorisation%20Categorisation%20is%20a%20process%20of%20modelling%20of%20a%20single%20subtype%20(or%20subclass)%20with%20a%20relationship%20that%20involves%20more%20than%20one%20distinct%20supertype%20(or%20superclass).&f=false

Comment: Me neither. What site is that?

Comment: i updated the site, plz check it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, formally categorization is a process of creating of a relation (category) that contains tupels that are a subset of the union of the tupels of the superclasses. The tupels for that subset are chosen based on certain characteristic. Consider an example:

Lets say, we have `Suppliers(id, name, address, email, bank_acct, paypal, ... etc.)` relation and `Customers(ssn, name, faname, email, address, paypal, ... etc.)` relation. So, we could create another relation featuring only those parties (both suppliers and customers) who have paypal accounts - `Paypal_account_holders(id, name, address, paypal_acct, email ... etc.)` where `Paypal_account_holders.id` is surrogate primary key for `Paypal_account_holders` and foreign key to both `Suppliers.paypal` and `Customers.paypal`.

Motivation and advantages:

- Universal interface for applications;
- Security. Restricted access to tables when you allow users to access only
  some part of information;
- Simplified queries;
- Enforcing some business rules for certain category;
- etc.

  Again, that's how I understand it.